# HTML/JS Text recognition variable displayer

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot get the `<div id="output">` section to display the variable `txtOutput` or maybe the variable `txtOutput` is not being defined or changed.
I would appreciate help on re-defining this variable or how to display it. (the empty text box feature works though)

```js
function smartinput() {
  var txtInput = document.forms["form"]["inputA"].value;
  var txtOutput;
  var input = txtInput.value;
  if (txtInput == null || txtInput == "") {
    alert("Please put text in Input");
    return false;
  } else if (txtInput == "Hi") {
    return output.value = "Hello";
  }
  document.getElementByID("Output").innerHTML = txtOutput;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Note:</strong> The output element is not supported in Edge 12 or Internet Explorer and earlier versions.</p>
<h1> Smart Responder Test 1 </h1>
<form name="form">
  <fieldset>
    <label> Input: </label>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="inputA" id="txtInput"></textarea>
    <p></p>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="smartinput()" />
    <p></p>

    <label>Output: </label>
    <div id="Output"></div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: If you run your code you'll see one error that you made is a typo. It's `getElementById` not `getElementByID`. JavaScript is case-sensitive. Also, what's `output` in `output.value`? You're also returning from your function before you can get to the innerHTML line

Comment: @ConnerQ , The console (**`F12`**) is you friend mate

Comment: Thanks, but changing ID did nothing, also the output value i changed to its  txtOutput value instead, but it did nothing

Comment: 1. Change `getElementByID` to `getElementById`. 2. Change `output.value` to `txtOutput`. 3. Get rid of the second `return`. You should also learn the fundamentals of debugging your JavaScript by using the browser's developer tools.

Comment: did that, but also did not work, im also using Notepad++

Comment: It works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/L1up0hrz/. What do you mean you're using Notepad++? Run your code in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you made a typo for method `getElementById`, correct that.

Secondly, you are defining variable `txtOutput` but not using it later, rather you use `output`. Just change `output` to `txtOutput`:

```
function smartinput() {
  var txtInput = document.forms["form"]["inputA"].value;
  var txtOutput;
  var input = txtInput.value;
  if (txtInput == null || txtInput == "") {
    alert("Please put text in Input");
    return false;
  } else if (txtInput == "Hi") {
    txtOutput= "Hello";
  }
  document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = txtOutput;
}
```

And you don't need `txtOutput.value` because it is only a variable for result.

Comment: thanks, but after doing that, it did nothing to change my problem.

Comment: I edite answer. You got unneeded `return` on `return txtOutput= "Hello";`

Answer (score 0):

Some errors

- you should put `getElementById` in place to `...byID`
- If it is empty or null, just put it like this `!(elem or value)`
- The output element is not a text area so value will not work. Change it to `innerHTML` or `innerText`
- `TxtInput` and `input` are the same in your code

```js
function smartinput() {
  var txtInput = document.forms["form"]["inputA"];
  var input = txtInput.value;
  var output = document.getElementById("Output");
  if (!input) {
    alert("Please put text in Input");
    return false;
  } else if (input == "Hi") {
    return output.innerHTML = "Hello";
  }
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Note:</strong> The output element is not supported in Edge 12 or Internet Explorer and earlier versions.</p><h1> Smart Responder Test 1 </h1><form name="form"><fieldset><label> Input: </label><textarea cols="30" rows="2" name="inputA" id="txtInput"></textarea><p></p><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="smartinput()" /><p></p><label>Output: </label><div id="Output"></div></fieldset></form>
```

Comment: This fixed it, Thanks so much!